# How would I go about using a string value, such as '100pF 50vdc' and query multiple different fields as part of a search?

Tags: php, mysql, search-form

This is the current query that is working

```
$query_CDC="SELECT * FROM ceramic_capacitors WHERE voltage LIKE '%$search%' OR vType LIKE '%$search%' OR CONCAT(voltage, vtype) LIKE '%$search%' OR value LIKE '%$search%' OR mult LIKE '%$search%' OR CONCAT(value, mult) LIKE '%$search%' OR source LIKE '%$search'";
```

I am trying to search the entire table, with spaces in the search field.
I added the CONCAT to the query, and it will only return entries when there are no spaces in the search field

Comment: Use a regular expression like `/^(\d+)([a-z]+)$/i` to split the input into number and multiplier.

Comment: Can you give me an example in context?

Comment: You could concatenate your two fields, adding something like `OR CONCAT(value, mult) LIKE '%$search%'`.
Keep in mind that as is, you are WIDE OPEN TO SQL INJECTIONS. This is not just a bad practice, it's a very high, very real security risk. Don't concatenate user input into your SQL queries. There's never an excuse for not using prepared statements. I urge you to look into them.

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of SQL injections, I am not too concerned about that rn, only because this will never actually be exposed to the wild lol it's an electronic component inventory app I've been writing to use on a ras-pi, or other devices, not public domain

Comment: After doing some thinking, where's a good site to learn PDO? I learned mysqli, because I find it to be more straight-forward, and just a little easier to grasp on to the flow of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a regular expression to split the search string.

```
if (preg_match('/^(\d+)([a-z]+)$/i', $search, $match)) {
    $number = $match[1];
    $mult = $match[2];
    // Then use $number and $mult in your query
}
```